# JavaScript/jQuery dynamically build HTML table from form input data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling to find a solution to the below. I have a HTML page with a form that a user can enter information on. There are 8 variables to enter, Once the user clicks submit on the form I want JQuery/JavaScript to create a dynamic table entry to populate the page with the information provided.

I have the table snippet I think I would use but I don't know where to start with the JS/JQ with having so many variables. Any pointers in the right direction would help

HMTL Form Data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Team Sheet</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Show Popup Form</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
      <form method="post" action="/action_page_post.php">
        <div>
          <h3>Team Entry</h3>
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable1:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable1">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable2:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable2">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable3:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable3">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable4:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable4">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable5:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable5">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable6:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable6">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable7:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable7">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable8:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable8">
          <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Get Calling!</h1>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamic HTML Table snippet

```
<tr>
<td>Variable1</td>
<td>Variable2</td>
<td>Variable3</td>
<td><a href="Variable4" target="_blank" target="_blank" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable5</a></td>
<td><a href="mailto:Variable6" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable6</a></td>
<td><a href="mailto:Variable7" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable7</a></td>
<td>Variable8</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: What is `action_page_post.php` for? Do you need PHP to play a role here?

Answer (score -1):

You could put the template inside a hidden table. Then on submission replace the "VariableX" text with the text from the corresponding inputs. For that it is easiest if you give each input that corresponding `id` value. Any way, the current `id` values are no good, since duplicates are not allowed in HTML.

Here is how that could work:

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
    var html = $("#template").html();
    $("input[type=text]", this).each(function () {
        html = html.split(this.id).join(this.value); 
    });
    $("#output").append($("<tr>").html(html)).show();
    $("#myPopup").popup('close');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Team Sheet</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Show Popup Form</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
      <form>
        <div>
          <h3>Team Entry</h3>
          <label for="Variable1" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable1:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable1" placeholder="Variable1">
          <label for="Variable2" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable2:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable2" placeholder="Variable2">
          <label for="Variable3" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable3:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable3" placeholder="Variable3">
          <label for="Variable4" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable4:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable4" placeholder="Variable4">
          <label for="Variable5" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable5:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable5" placeholder="Variable5">
          <label for="Variable6" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable6:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable6" placeholder="Variable6">
          <label for="Variable7" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable7:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable7" placeholder="Variable7">
          <label for="Variable8" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable8:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="Variable8" placeholder="Variable8">
          <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table id="output" class="ui-table" style="display:none">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Variable1</th>
        <th>Variable2</th>
        <th>Variable3</th>
        <th>Variable4</th>
        <th>Variable5</th>
        <th>Variable6</th>
        <th>Variable7</th>
        <th>Variable8</th>
      </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="template" style="display:none">
        <td>Variable1</td>
        <td>Variable2</td>
        <td>Variable3</td>
        <td><a href="Variable4" target="_blank" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable5</a></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:Variable6" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable6</a></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:Variable7" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable7</a></td>
        <td>Variable8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Get Calling!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to maximise the snippet output window when you run it, since otherwise the scrollbars will be a bit confusing to work with.